# Searching for similar string in eclipse using regex

Tags: regex, eclipse

I have following file:

```
<rules>
    <q>abc</q>
    <a>1</a>
    <q>bcd</q>
    <a>2</a>
    <q>abc</q>
    <a>3</a>
</rules>
<rules>
    <q>bcd</q>
    <a>2</a>
    <q>edc</q>
    <a>4</a>
    <q>abc</q>
    <a>3</a>
</rules>
```

I want to basically file  xml node with same text on search. So in this case i want to find abc when i search. Can someone please suggest regular expression for this? Or any other way to do this?

Comment: You probably want to use XPath instead of Regex: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

Comment: @JamesKingsbery - How can i use xPath this is very big file? I will have to write a code for that. Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: @NoviceMe What do you want to do with the elements once you find them?

Comment: @FailedDev - I dont want to do anything i am just looking for duplicate <q> elements thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enhancing FailedDev's answer a bit to get my wanted result. May be this will help somebody else looking for same thing:

```
//q[not(text() = '') and text() = following-sibling::q/text()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what features Eclipse regex supports, but this could work if supported:

```
<q>([^<]+)</q>.*<q>\1</q>
```

With some "dot matches new lines" flag (like `(?s)`).

Comment: This is in contrast with the "I want to find abc", and also not the tool for the job :)